# How to Read input from console in F#

Tags: f#

I'm write a Program to Consume input as from a Console Entry
`let line = Console.ReadLine()` 
It's give an Type Error.

Comment: This compiles fine for me. Please provide more context and the exact error message.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39429994/how-can-i-use-a-user-inputted-value-in-my-function-in-f

Answer (score 9, accepted):

are you missing

```
open System
```

alternatively  use

```
System.Console.ReadLine()
```